# specification does not match any backup in the repository

Tags: oracle, rman

i want to delete arhcivelog on my DB oracle.

```
RMAN> list backup of archivelog all;
specification does not match any backup in the repository
```

it seems there is not any of them.

but the recovery area is not empty.

```
 SELECT * FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;
 name                       space_limit     space_used    space_reclaimable      number of files
 /opt/oracle/recovery_area  21474836480     10529677312   0                      8


SQL> archive log list;
Database log mode              No Archive Mode
Automatic archival             Disabled
Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Oldest online log sequence     2081
Current log sequence           2083
```

what's wrong in my oracle? how to delete all archivelog?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all archivelog on disk no matter wether they are backed up or not

```
RMAN > delete archivelog all;
```

Delete all archivelog on disk no matter wether they are backed up or not having one day old.

```
RMAN > delete archivelog all completed before ‘sysdate -1′;
```